# Positive semidefiniteness in Boolean least-squares problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices, relaxations

A Boolean least-squares can be formulated as follows

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \operatorname{tr}(A^TAX) - 2b^TAx + b^Tb\\ \text{subject to} & X = xx^T\\ & X_{ii} = 1\end{array}

which can be further formulated as

$$\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{trace}(A^TAX) - 2b^TAx + b^Tb\\
=&\operatorname{trace}\left[(x^TA^T-b^T)(Ax - b)\right]\\
=&\operatorname{trace}\left[\pmatrix{x^T&1}\pmatrix{A^T\\ -b^T}\pmatrix{A&-b}\pmatrix{x\\ 1}\right]\\
=&\operatorname{trace}\left[\pmatrix{A^T\\ -b^T}\pmatrix{A&-b}\pmatrix{x\\ 1}\pmatrix{x^T&1}\right]\\
=&\operatorname{trace}\left[
\underbrace{\pmatrix{A^TA&-A^Tb\\ -b^TA&b^Tb}}_B
\underbrace{\pmatrix{X&x\\ x^T&1}}_Y\right].
\end{align*}$$

and we require the $Y \succeq 0$ (I just omit other constraints here for simplicity). So, is the expression of $X\succeq xx^T$ equvilant to the expression of $Y\succeq0$? As I saw this equivalence in Professor Boyd's convex optimization PPT, but I don't how to prove it.

Reference

1. Convex Optimization [[PDF]](https://mathtube.org/sites/default/files/lecture-notes/Boyd_Stephen.pdf).

Comment: $X_{ii} = 1$ seems a little restrictive, did you mean $\in \{0,1\}$?

Comment: No, I think for "boolean least square", it is meant for $X_{ii}=1$ or $x_i^2 = 1$. I will add the corresponding PPT of the convex optimization and you could check the page 32 about it.

Comment: I met Stephen when he was a graduate student.

Comment: I think my question here is actually about the equvilance between $Y\succeq 0 $ and $X\succeq xx^T$. As in the PPT it was said to be equvilant, but I don't quite figure out how to prove it. Sorry for adding too much contents about boolean least squares.

Comment: Use the [Schur Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) (particularly the section "Conditions for positive definiteness and semi-definiteness")

Comment: @p.s. Thanks! I will check it!

Comment: The equivalent is straightforward, but the abuse of $x,X$ is inexcusable.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/755688/339790)

Comment: @copper.hat El Ghaoui on [Boolean LS](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eelghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/hw1.pdf).  Boyd on [Boolean LS](https://mathtube.org/sites/default/files/lecture-notes/Boyd_Stephen.pdf) (slides 32-33)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\begin{bmatrix} A & v \\ v^T & 1 \end{bmatrix} \ge 0$.

Then $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} A & v \\ v^T & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix} = x^T Ax +2 \alpha x^Tv + \alpha^2 \ge 0$. Choose $\alpha = - x^T v$ to obtain $A \ge v v^T$.

For the other direction, suppose $A  \ge v v^T$, then
$x^T Ax +2 \alpha x^Tv + \alpha^2 \ge (x^Tv)^2+ 2 \alpha x^Tv + \alpha^2 \ge (x^Tv)^2 = (x^T v + \alpha)^2 \ge 0$.